# When JWT token expiration should be checked with a state management library in React?

Tags: reactjs

I've just started using a React routing libray and a state management library.

1. After a successfully login, **JWT token is stored in the state**

After some time, depending on the server, the token exipires. I need to remove the stored JWT token and force the user to navigate to the `/login` page again.

Where to check for the token expiration and redirect the user?

1. Lot of people suggest to do it with a **router listener**
2. Other people suggest to check every server response and **look for 401 Unauthorized**

**Problem**: approach 1 doesn't work if the user stay on the same page and hit a button that doesn't change the current route. The approach 2 depends on the request library one is using.

So what's the correct way to check for the expiration?